# Why is my array is returning to the test empty?

Tags: javascript, arrays, jestjs

I am in a programming languages class, and this week we are working on JavaScript. I have gotten all of the tests to work except for this one:

```
  ● powers › generates sequences of powers properly

    expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality

    - Expected  - 3
    + Received  + 1

    - Array [
    -   1,
    - ]
    + Array []

      82 |     expect(generatorToArray(powers, 2, -5)).toEqual([]);
      83 |     expect(generatorToArray(powers, 7, 0)).toEqual([]);
    > 84 |     expect(generatorToArray(powers, 3, 1)).toEqual([1]);
         |                                            ^
      85 |     expect(generatorToArray(powers, 2, 63)).toEqual([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]);
      86 |     expect(generatorToArray(powers, 2, 64)).toEqual([1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64]);
      87 |   });

      at Object.<anonymous> (h2.test.js:84:44)

  console.log h2.js:41
    []

  console.log h2.js:41
    []

  console.log h2.js:41
    [ 1 ]
```

The idea is to have it return all of the powers of a number, x, up to a certain point, y. As you can see, the console.log shows the array as having [1] in it, while it is being returned to the test as [] empty. Here is the source code:

```
function powers(x, y){
    let count = 0;
    let z = new Array();
    while(Math.pow(x,count)<=y){
        z.push(Math.pow(x,count));
        count+=1;
    }
    console.log(z);
    return z;
}
```

I have racked my brains, and I sincerely have no idea what could be wrong with this. Please help!

EDIT: Here is the generatorToArray function, all of the tests were provided by the professor so I don't think I'm allowed to change them.

```
function generatorToArray(generator, ...args) {
  const result = [];
  generator(...args, (item) => result.push(item));
  return result;
}
```

Comment: The function you've posted shouldn't fail on this test case. `powers(3, 1)` evaluates to `[1]`. The problem must be in `generatorToArray`

Comment: You have to show us what `generatorToArray` functions is

Comment: `generatorToArray(powers, 3, 1)` seems to be called with 3 arguments but your `powers` function is defined to only have 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `generatorToArray` a function that has to be like that and you can't change it? If so, the function expects the `generator` - the `power` function - to have the last argument being called as a callback with the result.

I.e. the *generator* should *generate* the results - that's what the callback is for - the callback is called for each generated partial result. The `generatorToArray` function then collects these generated partial results into an array.

So the `power` function should not create its own array, it should just call the callback with the each partial result:

```
function powers(x, y, callback){
    let count = 0;
    while(Math.pow(x,count)<=y){
        callback(Math.pow(x,count));
        count+=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! That did the trick. I would have never guessed that, I suppose I need to take a closer look at the test functions every now and again. Thank you so much!